# How to insert selected rows with another column sequence?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have to change a database structure. We have several tables with the same columns (mostly), now I'd like to move it to children of one parent table, then move data from old scattered tables to new (inherited) ones.

So, the two tables (inherited **comments_temp** and primary **comments**) have identical structure, but different column order:

```
\d comments
  Column   |            Type             |                           Modifiers
------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------
 comment_id | bigint                      | not null default nextval('comments_comment_id_seq'::regclass)
 post_id    | bigint                      | not null
 auser_id   | bigint                      | not null
 dt         | timestamp without time zone | not null
 text       | text                        | not null
 is_deleted | smallint                    | default 0
 parent     | bigint                      | default 0
                     | default 0

\d comments_temp
   Column   |            Type             |                             Modifiers
------------+-----------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
 comment_id | bigint                      | not null default nextval('comments_base_comment_id_seq'::regclass)
 auser_id   | bigint                      | not null
 dt         | timestamp without time zone | not null
 text       | text                        | not null
 is_deleted | smallint                    | default 0
 parent     | bigint                      | default 0
 post_id    | bigint                      | not null
Inherits: comments_base
```

The insertion fails because of another order of columns (despite the fact columns in a copied table and columns in a new table matches).

```
INSERT INTO comments_temp ( SELECT * FROM comments );
```

So, I've got a error on INSERT:

```
ERROR:  column "dt" is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type bigint
LINE 1: INSERT INTO comments_temp ( SELECT * FROM comments );
                                           ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

How to insert by select when order of columns is *different* in PostgreSQL? I'd like not to use exclicit column names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the columns in your insert:

```
INSERT INTO comments_temp(comment_id, auser_id, dt, text, is_deleted, parent, post_id)
SELECT comment_id, auser_id, dt, text, is_deleted, parent, post_id FROM comments;
```

Comment: Excuse me. Probably I made the edit after your answer: *I'd like not to use exclicit column names.* There are many tables. Of course it's the solution, but I need a simplier one.

Comment: @sergzach I don't think there is a way to do it without specifying the columns if the order is not the same. You can use dynamic SQL and generate the column-names automatically, or use a tool to generate the queries for you. As for the second part, it is only unnecessary if the first part specifies **ALL** the columns in the **SAME** order as the table in the second part.